# ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] City validation failed: weather: Cast to string failed

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create a city then making a request to OpenWeatherMap api to get the weather info of this city then store it into DB (MongoDB Atlas).
But I cannot a proper schema type for the weather field, I tried to use 'Mixed' but it's not recognized

Structure

```
|- cities
|- |  city.model.ts
|- |  cities.controller.ts
|- |  cities.service.ts
```

`city.model.ts`

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export const CitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  weather: String,
});

export interface City {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  weather: mongoose.Mixed;
}
```

`cities.controller.ts`

```
@Controller('cities')
export class CitiesController {
  constructor(private readonly citiesService: CitiesService) {}

  @Post()
  createCity(@Body() createCityDto: CreateCityDto) {
    return this.citiesService.createCity(createCityDto);
  }
}
```

`cities.service.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class CitiesService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('City') private readonly cityModel: Model<City>,
    private readonly httpService: HttpService
    ) {}

  async createCity(createCityDto: CreateCityDto) {
    const { name } = createCityDto;

    // Get city weather from OpenWeatherMap
    const weather = this.httpService
      .get(
        `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${name}&appid=${process.env.OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY}`,
      )
      .pipe(map((response) => response.data));

    const city = new this.cityModel({
      name,
      weather,
    });

    await city.save();

    return city;
  }
}
```

`cities.module.ts`

```
...

@Module({
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'City', schema: CitySchema }]),
  ],
  controllers: [CitiesController],
  providers: [CitiesService],
})
export class CitiesModule {}
```

Error

```
[Nest] 12852  - 22/12/2021, 10:35:21     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +7ms
[Nest] 12852  - 22/12/2021, 10:35:27   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] City validation failed: weather: Cast to string failed for value "Observable {
  source: Observable { _subscribe: [Function (anonymous)] },
  operator: [Function (anonymous)]
}" (type Observable) at path "weather"
ValidationError: City validation failed: weather: Cast to string failed for value "Observable {
  source: Observable { _subscribe: [Function (anonymous)] },
  operator: [Function (anonymous)]
}" (type Observable) at path "weather"
    at model.Document.invalidate (C:\Users\ouss\Desktop\coffeeit-assessment\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2921:32)
    at model.$set (C:\Users\ouss\Desktop\coffeeit-assessment\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1458:12)
    at model.$set (C:\Users\ouss\Desktop\coffeeit-assessment\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1153:16)
    at model.Document (C:\Users\ouss\Desktop\coffeeit-assessment\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:158:12)
    at model.Model (C:\Users\ouss\Desktop\coffeeit-assessment\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:107:12)
    at new model (C:\Users\ouss\Desktop\coffeeit-assessment\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4777:15)
    at CitiesService.createCity (C:\Users\ouss\Desktop\coffeeit-assessment\src\cities\cities.service.ts:29:18)
    at CitiesController.createCity (C:\Users\ouss\Desktop\coffeeit-assessment\src\cities\cities.controller.ts:11:31)
    at C:\Users\ouss\Desktop\coffeeit-assessment\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:38:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this piece of code and it seems to be working

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export const CitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  weather: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Mixed,
});

export interface City {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  weather: mongoose.Mixed;
}
```

But if you have any feedback or a better solution I'm all ears